# SVG text element height/width inside of display:none container

Tags: d3.js, svg

I've got an SVG that is being drawn inside of a div that has css of `display:none`. I need to center some of the rendered text elements, and to do this, I need the height and width. Unfortunately, when the containing html element is set to `display:none`, I always get 0 for height, and width. `getBBox(), clientWidth, getComputedTextLength()` methods all return zero. My question is: how can text width be calculated under these conditions?

e.g.

```
<div style='display:none;'>
<svg><g><text>some text</text></g></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get the width using the `textLength` property of the text element. I'm not sure if it is also affected by the `div` display property.

Comment: Set `display` to visible, get the bounding box, then immediately set display to `none` again.

Comment: @Lars good suggestion! It has crossed my mind too, but it's a hack, I was hoping for a more permanent solution, that lends itself to separation of concerns. The div is controlled by a modal dialog angular controller which is display none until the user clicks a button, and the chart is rendered via another component, it would be kind of bad for the chart component to be in the business of manipulating parent markup that isn't its own.

Comment: @James Well the only "safe" way to get the dimensions of an element is to ask the browser to render it, so this is probably the way you'll have to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `<div>` to `visibility: hidden;`?

You may also want to make it `position: absolute;` so it doesn't affect the layout of other items on the page.

Comment: The best, position absolute with top:-100000px, left:-100000px;